# Can I make a 3ds thumb stick less likely to crack?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I play a lot of Monster Hunter and my thumb stick on my 3ds keeps cracking can I make it stronger like the Xbox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buy a stronger thumb stick that doesn't have the rubber piece.

Comment: is there any particular reason why the link was removed?